# How to use CLSStackFrame in the Crashlytics?

Tags: ios, crashlytics, google-fabric

I use [this](https://docs.fabric.io/appledocs/Crashlytics/Classes/Crashlytics.html#//api/name/recordCustomExceptionName:reason:frameArray:) method to record errors with Crashlytics. Because only it allow to record custom message. It's interesting to me how i can improve crash message, so maybe i can send a stack trace with [CLSStackFrame](https://docs.fabric.io/appledocs/Crashlytics/Classes/CLSStackFrame.html) argument? How to use it?

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Yes, if you want to record an exception from another language using that method and the StackFrame argument is what you would want to do.

Comment: Please add an answer with an example. It would make the life simplier and the Internet fuller)

Comment: The problem is that these functionality is intended for a variety of languages. I would recommend posting what you've tried so that clarity can be given where it might be failing.

Comment: I just think about how i can use this to add the additional info for crash.